# inject entitymanager with spring jpa not working

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a training small application with Eclipse  using Spring and Jpa . when I inject Entitymanager it s give an error  that it's NULL .
I googled a lot and tried to understand if I miss semething and read official docs but I couldn't find out the source of the problem. any help is appreciated . I joined the console after run the main class.

spring-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd   
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                       ">
       <context:component-scan base-package="src/ben" />
       <tx:annotation-driven /> 

       <bean id="hello" class="ben.Hello">
             <property name="message" value="Bonjour"> </property>
       </bean>

 <bean id="myEmf"
     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
       <property name="packagesToScan" value="ben" />
       <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="BenJpaProject"></property>
       <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
           <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
       </property>
       <property name="jpaProperties">
          <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
          </props>
       </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="dataSource"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
          <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
          <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.56.4.101:1552/dev1002" />      
          <property name="username" value="ISPOWNRE6" />
          <property name="password" value="ISPOWNRE6" />

   </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager"
     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
       <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
   </bean>


   <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class=
     "org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

 <bean  id="personDao"  class="ben.AbstractBaseDao" />

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" 
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="BenJpaProject" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>ben.Person</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="ISPOWNRE6" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="ISPOWNRE6" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.56.4.101:1552:dev1002" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class " />
         </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Class to use EntityManager :

```
package ben;

@Repository
public class AbstractBaseDao
{
private EntityManager em;

  @PersistenceContext
  public void setEm(EntityManager em)
  {
    this.em = em;
  }


  public <T> T findById (Class <T> clazz,Serializable code)
  {
     return em.find(clazz, code);
  }
```

}

Main class :

```
public class MainJpa
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/spring-context.xml");

    PersonDaoImpl personDaoImpl=new PersonDaoImpl();
    Person person=personDaoImpl.findPersonById((long) 10);
    System.out.println("person Found "+person);
  }

}
```

class  PersonDaoImpl :

```
public class PersonDaoImpl extends AbstractBaseDao implements  PersonDao
{

  @Override
  public Person findPersonById(Long id)
  {
    Class <Person> clazz=Person.class;
    return findById(clazz, id);

  }
```

Console after run the main class:

```
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:22 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1698c449: startup date [Fri Sep 14 11:29:22 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:22 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/spring-context.xml]
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:23 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:23 AM org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager readPersistenceUnitInfos
INFO: Found explicit default unit with name 'BenJpaProject' in persistence.xml - overriding local default unit settings ('packagesToScan'/'mappingResources')
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:23 AM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'BenJpaProject'
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:23 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: BenJpaProject
    ...]
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:23 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:23 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:23 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:24 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:25 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:26 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:26 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table Person cascade constraints
Hibernate: create table Person (id number(19,0) not null, numero number(19,0), primary key (id))
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:27 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Sep 14, 2018 11:29:27 AM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean buildNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'BenJpaProject'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ben.AbstractBaseDao.findById(AbstractBaseDao.java:38)
    at ben.PersonDaoImpl.findPersonById(PersonDaoImpl.java:12)
    at ben.MainJpa.main(MainJpa.java:14)
```

Comment: try changing package name of `<context:component-scan base-package="src/ben" />` to `ben`, as `<context:component-scan base-package="ben" />`

Comment: changed but still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work when you go and create Spring beans by yourself. In your `main` class you do

```
PersonDaoImpl personDaoImpl=new PersonDaoImpl();
```

How should Spring know that this bean exists? It doesn't and, thus, it can't inject anything into it. You have to let Spring create beans, via JavaConfig, XML or you create them programmatically through the *ApplicationContext*.

Try this main method instead of yours:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext context = 
     new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/spring-context.xml");

  PersonDaoImpl personDaoImpl = context.getBean(PersonDaoImpl.class);
  Person person = personDaoImpl.findPersonById((long) 10);
  System.out.println("person Found "+person);
}
```

... and your `PersistenceContext` should be injected into your DAO.

This sample is just for demonstration purposes. I'd propose that you register your beans in your `spring-context.xml` like this

```
<bean name="personDao" class="ben.PersonDaoImpl"/>
```

Then you can easily autowire them in other beans like this

```
@Autowired
private PersonDao personDao;
```